# Is there a way to taker user input as a txt file and then rewrite it into a new txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a program where the user inputs their txt file. The txt file is read and then the txt file is written into a new txt file. The new txt file has one word on each line. I am able to write the program without the user input and it works perfectly. Once I add the user input it tells me the txt file does not exist in my directory (even though it does). Am I not sure what I am doing wrong. Please point me in the direction of easy tutorials I can watch to solve this problem.

This is the code that doesn't work

```
outputString = " "

userinput = input('Enter the name of the file you want to read:' + " ")

myfile = open(userinput, 'r')

myOutputFile = open(userinput_Output, 'a')


for line in myfile:
    words = line.split()

    for current in words:
        myOutputFile.write(current + "\n")
        
myfile.close()

myOutputFile.close()
```

This is the code that works (you can test it out with your own txt files and see that it does actually work if you don't want to take my word for it.)

```
outputString = " "

myfile = open("readme.txt", 'r')

myOutputFile = open("readme_Output.txt", 'a')


for line in myfile:
    words = line.split()

    for current in words:
        myOutputFile.write(current + "\n")
        
myfile.close()

myOutputFile.close()
```

Comment: If this isn’t answered by morning, I’ll try to post a fix to your code. I’m mobile right now. Just posting this comment so I can find your question in the morning.

Comment: because `userinput_Output` does not make sense...  you would need to change to `userinput + "_Output.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is because `userinput_Output` is not defined.

What you need to do is **concatenate** `userinput` to `_Output.txt`.

I have flagged where the correction would go in the code below.

```py
userinput = input('Enter the name of the file you want to read: ')

# open the files
path = 'C:/path/to/folder/with/files/'
myfile = open(path + userinput+'.txt', 'r')
myOutputFile = open(path + userinput+"_output.txt", 'a')   # <---  this line


for line in myfile:
    words = line.split()

    for current in words:
        myOutputFile.write(current + "\n")
        
# close the files
myfile.close()
myOutputFile.close()
```

Here are the data results.

example input text file (`test.txt`):

```
hello world
hello moon
```

resulting output text file (`test_output.txt`):

```
hello
world
hello
moon
```

As an extra, you can open both files in a context manager (which handles closing both automatically, like this) which is much cleaner:

```py
userinput = input('Enter the name of the file you want to read: ')

path = 'C:/path/to/folder/with/files/'
input_file = os.path.join(path, userinput + '.txt')
output_file = os.path.join(path, userinput + '_output.txt')

with open(input_file, 'r') as myfile, open(output_file, 'a') as myOutputFile:
    for line in myfile:
        words = line.split()
        for current in words:
            myOutputFile.write(current + "\n")
```

Comment: Hi @D.L.  Thank you for the explanation. However, I tried that and I still get the following error:                                                                                                                                  
Enter the name of the file: readme.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Katie\CSIT 500\Mileto_Katherine_a6.py", line 12, in <module>
    myfile = open(userinput, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'readme.txt'                                            This file does exist on my computer though.

Comment: if the file is not in the same folder then you would need to apply the **full** path to the file. This is basically what a "No such file or directory" is telling you....

Comment: I am assuming that you mean the txt file and the saved python program are in the same folder, which they are. Thus my problem. I have even used the full the path as well and I still get an error message.

Comment: For clarification the same txt file can be accessed without issue when I use it in the code without asking for user input.

Comment: i have modified the code to include **the full path to the files** (replace with your full path).  I have tested this on my pc and it works (using windows, for mac and linux it is backslashes in the folder path)...

Comment: Thank you. But I am not sure I understand. How I am supposed to replace the full path to the file if I do not know where the user keeps their file?

Comment: if you don't know where the user keeps the file, then how are you reading the file in the first place ?  ...you must know the file location.

Comment: This is an assignment for a computer science class. I am to make a program that asks the user to input a txt file and the program then makes a new txt file where each word of the file is on a new line. That is what I am trying to do. So, no I do not know where the user keeps the file. It should be on their computer some where. Are you telling me that it is impossible to write a program that does that?

Comment: The code **must** know the location of the file that it is reading. Otherwise, how could it read it ?

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I appreciate the feedback.